# Symbols in Output After Removing Spaces From Read File in C

Tags: c, file-io

So basically below is snippets of the code where the problem is occurring.

My objective is to scan a list of names from the file and alphabetize them.
I have only included code for the first name from the file below essentially.
The problem is after they are scanned in if I print it out straight away I get symbols looking like ┬á┬á┬á┬á where (I'm assuming) there are spaces in the file.

But even after I remove the spaces at least I think I do these symbols still appear whenever printing.

So all I want to do is get rid of them god damn symbols!

```
    if (ini == 1 || both ==1){
    fr1 = fopen ("players.txt", "r");
    }
    if(fr1 == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return(-1);
    }
    fgets(line, 1000, fr1);
    fclose(fr1);

    while(line[inputCount] != '\0'){
        inputCount++;
    }

    j = 0;
    while(line[j] != '\0'){
        if(line[j] == ' '){
            for(int k = j;k<=inputCount;k++){
            line[k] = line[k+1];
            }
            --inputCount;
        }
        j++;
    }

    for (j=0; j<inputCount; j++){
    printf("%c",line[j]); 
    }
```

this is just a separate snip of code I tried to no avail either.

```
    int count = 0; 
    for(i=0; i < inputCount; i ++){
    char ch = line[i];
    switch (ch) {
    case '.':
    case ',': count = 0; break;
    case ' ': count++; continue;
    default: for ( ; count; count--) putc(' ', stdout); break;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) break;
    putc(ch, stdout);
    }
```

The above piece of code was robbed off this site I do believe but unless I used it wrong; as I don't 100% understand it, I'm not going to lie; it did not work either

Comment: Did you initialize `inputCount` to `0` before the `while()` loop?

Comment: Are you prohibited from using `strlen(line)`?

Comment: yes input count to 0 was initialized

Comment: `if (ch == EOF)` unsure about this, since `line` must be a `char[]` array which cannot store an `int` value.

Comment: not prohibited from anything as far I'm aware, I just don't know many functions I will give it a look now though thank you

Comment: Hi weather vane as I said I actually just robbed that bottom piece of code as something else to try so I am not 100% on it at all

Comment: There's no need to check for `EOF` in the `line` array. `fgets()` will never return a line that contains `EOF`.

Comment: `inputCount = strlen(line);` this is really basic C.

Comment: okay yeah thanks @barmar strlen(line) will definitely help in this and the future! although wont get rid of the symbols I don't think.

Comment: The second loop is to get rid of spaces in the line, right? I think it will have a problem if the last character of the line is a space and there's no newline after it. The `line[j] != '\0'` test will never test the last character after it's shifted down, because `j++` will skip over it.

Comment: I'm sorry @barmar I am only at a basic level, I am trying

Comment: @barmar well at the moment there are essentially 10 lines each with a players name on it and I take in each line individually to a separate string.. ranging from line1-10 and preform all the code from above on each individually. So I'm not sure whether or not a new line even comes in to it?

Comment: Can you provide the full code of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't see anything obvious in what you've posted that would cause this.

Comment: got my friend to run it on his computer and he had no symbols, guessing it is just my computer or a compiler error